# setKeepAliveTimeout suddenly stopped after a few hours

Tags: ios, objective-c, voip

Scheduling a `setKeepAliveTimeout` with minimum timer of 600 seconds make my app works great for a few hours (6-7) hours.

```
/////////// VOIP HANLDER - BEGIN ///////////
    BOOL handlerAccepted = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setKeepAliveTimeout:kINTERVAL_10_MINUTES handler:^{        
        CLLocation *currentLocation = [RegionMonitoringService sharedInstance].locationManager.location;

#ifdef DEBUG
        NSString *locationDescription = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"VOIP Location: {%f, %f}, Time: %@",
                                         currentLocation.coordinate.latitude, currentLocation.coordinate.longitude,
                                         [currentLocation.timestamp description]];
        NSLog(@"setKeepAliveTimeout, %@", locationDescription);
        // GeneratePushNotification(locationDescription);
#endif

        [[ServerApiManager sharedInstance] saveLocation:currentLocation];

        // Register a geofence
        [[RegionMonitoringService sharedInstance] startMonitoringForLocation:currentLocation];
    }];

#ifdef DEBUG
    NSLog(@"VOIP handler installed: %@", handlerAccepted?@"YES":@"NO");
#endif
/////////// VOIP HANLDER - END ///////////
```

It happens to me in all of the devices i've been testing.
Why does it happen?

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: Why the block stopped relaunching itself and how can I revive it?